# Regular expression replace characters by a given match between strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace a given character by a regular expression match.
For example, given the following string:
*If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough*
I would like to replace all 't' with a '!' only where the match is between the characters 'ok' and 'fe'.

I get the match between 'ok' and 'fe' with this regular expression:

```
(?<=ok).*?(?=fe)
```

And I can only match one character with the following regex:

```
(?<=ok).*?(t).*?(?=fe)
```

I tried to transform that regex in the following way but it does not work:

```
(?<=ok).*?((t).*?)*?(?=fe)
```

How can I match all 't' between 'ok' and 'fe'?
https://regex101.com/r/ORgseA/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```java
String result = text.replaceAll("(?s)(\\G(?!\\A)|ok)((?:(?!ok|fe|t).)*)t(?=(?:(?!ok|fe).)*fe)", "$1$2!");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2I90G/2) and the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/4Ow654):

```java
String text = "If you look at what you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look at what you don't have in life, you'll never have enough";
String result = text.replaceAll("(?s)(\\G(?!\\A)|ok)((?:(?!ok|fe|t).)*)t(?=(?:(?!ok|fe).)*fe)", "$1$2!");
System.out.println(result);
// => If you look a! wha! you have in life, you'll always have more. If you look a! wha! you don'! have in life, you'll never have enough
```

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option (to make `.` match line break chars)
- `(\G(?!\A)|ok)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `ok` or the end of the previous successful match
- `((?:(?!ok|fe|t).)*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any one char, zero or more occurrences, as many as possible, that does not start a `ok`, `fe` or `t` char sequence
- `t`  - a `t` char
- `(?=(?:(?!ok|fe).)*fe)` - immediately to the right, there must be any single char, zero or more occurrences, as many as possible, that does not start `ok` or `fe` char sequences and then a `fe` substring.

Comment: Very nice  with the  `\G` ++

Comment: Wow awesome answer. Thank you so much. Now I just need to understand the "Details" part with a coffee :)

Comment: @Davide If you wonder what these `(?:(?!xxx).)*` mean, you can read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970).

Comment: After analysis, I would like to add the following thing. If we want to replace several characters for a '!', we only need to enclose all the characters we want to replace in a group, e.g. (t|w|h). If we don't enclose them in a group, characters outise the range 'ok' and 'fe' are also replaced.

Comment: @Davide Sure, but you should consider using a non-capturing group, they are used to match alternative patterns that we need to remove from a string, we only capture what we want to keep. And put single chars into a character class. So, in the case of `(t|w|h)`, use `[twh]`. If you had `(t|w|hd)` you could use `(?:hd|[tw])`.

Comment: Uh yes :) I absolutely agree